# A Meteor publication or subscription returns an array of objects when it should return just one object

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I am trying to do a publication where it returns the group that has the code attribute equal to users `selectedGroup`.

```
Meteor.publish('selectedGroup', function () {
  return Groups.findOne({
    code: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).profile.selectedGroup
  })
})
```

and the subscription looks like this

```
Meteor.subscribe('selectedGroup')
return {
  group: Groups.find({}).fetch()
}
```

But what I get is an array of all the groups that the user belongs to, and not the group that the publication should be returning.

Even when I do findOne() it returns the first object and not the one that the publication should be returning.

Comment: Is there anything else subscribing to the Groups collection?

Comment: there is but not in this component.

Comment: that could be important. if both subscriptions are active, Meteor will merge what's published. your client-side find(), above, doesn't do any filtering, so it will show everything that's been published to the client.

Comment: I am actually subscribing to the groups in the header!

Comment: how can I work around that?

Comment: I typically do client-side filtering to ensure I get exactly what I want, in case the publish does something unexpected, or someone adds an active subscription.

Comment: okay that makes sense, I'm quite new with meteor and this is really the first app Ive tried to make in meteor. So how could I pass that selectedGroup attribute into the createContainer so that I can filter it there?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by createContainer (is React involved somehow?), but you'd either have to publish that info or make a Meteor.call() to get it. it depends on how you set up your app and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use `findOne` in your publication - publications should return a cursor; in this case you will be publishing a single-document cursor (as long as only a single document in Groups matches the query). Just use `find` in the publication.

Second, when you're fetching the data on the client, you should make your query appropriately specific. Currently you're fetching *all* groups to which your client is subscribed (presumably you have other publications and subscriptions running.) See [here](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#fetching) for the Meteor Guide's advice. You'll want to do something like this in your container:

```
return {
  group: Groups.findOne({
    code: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).profile.selectedGroup
  })
}
```

Finally, if your user's selectedGroup can change, you should be aware that the data that publications provide can change, but their queries can't. So if your user's selectedGroup changes, the publication won't reflect this - as its query won't change. See [here](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publishing-relations). So you will want to use the [reactive publish package](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) to deal with this.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful!